# Rails Tutorial Chapter 10 exercise 5 Using partials to eliminate duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, partials

I'm new in Rails and as many others I'm learning it with Hartl's Rails Tutorial.
But on the exercise 5 chapter 10 (Using partials  to eliminate duplication) I'm totally stucked and I would like go on with clarity. Using stackoverflow I found a solution but it doesn't work for me.
In my case "delete" links just don't appear.
My files:

**app/views/shared/_feed_item.html.erb**

```
<li id="<%= feed_item.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(feed_item.user), feed_item.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_item.user.name, feed_item.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= feed_item.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_item.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(feed_item.user) %>
  <% render partial: 'shared/delete_link', locals: { object: feed_item } %>
  <% end %>
 </li>
```

**app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb**

```
<li>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(micropost.user) %>
  <% render partial: 'shared/delete_link', locals: { object: micropost } %>
  <% end %>
  </li>
```

**app/views/shared/_delete_link.html.erb**

```
 <%= link_to "delete", object, method: :delete,
                                     data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                     title: object.content %>
```

I don't get why "delete" link doesn't render. Condition `current_user?` succesfully performs... Situation as  if `<% render partial: 'shared/delete_link', locals: { object: feed_item } %>` don't even exist. Zero profit. If someone could enlighten me about this case I would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `<% render partial: 'shared/delete_link', locals: { object: feed_item } %>` to `<%= render partial: 'shared/delete_link', locals: { object: feed_item } %>`

Comment: Explanation: `<%` evaluates but does not output it's result, where `<%=` does.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very ashamed. Because of typo stole your time. Sorry, hope it won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

We can chip away at this a little bit by axing the `partial:` and the `locals:`.

That is, this works too: `<%= render 'shared/delete_link', object: feed_item %>`